# how to auto login with google when user kill app

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0

My app can comment on youtube's video and login with Google account.

(I use [Google Objective-C API Client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/))

When user kill the app, session is disappear.

I want to know the solution to do automate re-authenticate for Google API access.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know the api, but I'm pretty sure that when you do the login this api returns you a token to use in all the others requests. So, long story short, your app should make persistent the credentials returned after doing a login.

Answer (score 0):

use `NSUserDefaults` to store login details when user login and remove login details when user logout in your app AppleReference:[NSUserDefaults Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)